# Setting dtypes from pd.DataFrame gives TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, types, runtime-error

Lets suppose I have a dataframe and would like to set datatypes to all columns just like then I call `read_csv` method. For simplicity same error `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`  gives this piece of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,2,3], columns = ['num'], dtype={'num':int})
```

What is wrong here and how to make it work?

Full error stack:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e8a84bf74364> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,2,3], columns = ['num'], dtype={'num':int})

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    264             data = {}
    265         if dtype is not None:
--> 266             dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
    267 
    268         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _validate_dtype(self, dtype)
    145 
    146         if dtype is not None:
--> 147             dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
    148 
    149             # a compound dtype

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py in pandas_dtype(dtype)
   1895 
   1896     try:
-> 1897         npdtype = np.dtype(dtype)
   1898     except (TypeError, ValueError):
   1899         raise

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py in _usefields(adict, align)
     60         names = None
     61     if names is None:
---> 62         names, formats, offsets, titles = _makenames_list(adict, align)
     63     else:
     64         formats = []

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py in _makenames_list(adict, align)
     28     for fname in fnames:
     29         obj = adict[fname]
---> 30         n = len(obj)
     31         if not isinstance(obj, tuple) or n not in [2, 3]:
     32             raise ValueError("entry not a 2- or 3- tuple")

TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Comment: That means `obj` is a type. e.g., `int`, `str`... In your case, you passed `int` to the dtype. I would suggest you read the document carefully to get the correct format of input paramter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), I quote :

> dtype : dtype, default None
>   Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer

In short, you must specify only one dtype, and cannot pass a dictionary.

Example from doc...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, dtype=np.int8)
df.dtypes
#col1    int8
#col2    int8
#dtype: object
```